# How to send token in every request without using cookies or service worker?

Tags: javascript, authentication, session, playframework

I am trying to develop a web application using play framework 2.5 and jquery. I have got a use case where I cannot use cookies or service worker, but I need to send token in every request. I can generate a session_token for every user session and i can store that session_token in local storage.

Is there a way to intercept all types of requests and attach token in the request header? Requests which include opening a new webpage (window.location.href) or ajax request or form-submits or any redirects.

Answer (score 0):

You can send your authentication payload simply in your request header like this

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'YOUR_ENDPOINT',
  headers: { 'x-my-custom-header': 'some value' }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. To make it more clear I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try this code down below and it should intercept each request and attach an authentication header to it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   
    $.ajaxSetup({
         beforeSend: function(xhr) {
             xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', YourToken);
             return true;
         }
     });
}
```

Make sure the code is wrapped up inside the jQuery(document).ready() as mentioned above. Please let me know if that works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

check [proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) object if you are using Javascript ES6.

*Storing your token in local storage is subject to XSS attacks. Using service worker is one of the secure solutions when your javascript is dealing with such tokens.*